# Exception on accessing a class in Web API

Tags: c#, dictionary, concurrency, asp.net-web-api2, concurrentdictionary

I am encountering a weird behavior. My Web API suddenly cannot be used because of this exception:

```
[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: String]
   System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) +14198596
   System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) +177
   Dota2IoT.Server.Models.ViewModels.NatMappingManager..cctor() +112

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Dota2IoT.Server.Models.ViewModels.NatMappingManager' threw an exception.]
   Dota2IoT.Server.MvcApplication.Application_Start() +223
```

And this is the constructor of `NapMappingManager`:

```
    private ConcurrentDictionary<int, NatMappingViewModel> mappings;

    private NatMappingManager()
    {
        this.mappings = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, NatMappingViewModel>();
    }
```

Previously, I didn't even call `NapMappingManager` from the Global.asax `Application_Start`, but I think it may be because of some concurrent. However, now I try to call:

```
// Initialize the NAT
Models.ViewModels.NatMappingManager.Instance.ToString()
```

So the constructor can be called, but the same error happens. What's wrong with it? Did I do something with the code, or a bug from `ConcurrentDictionary`?

EDIT: The exception does not happen on my local machine. It only happens on my Azure VM (Window Server 2012) server.

EDIT to clarify for the correct answer:

This is the code that causes the problem (I do not have explicit static constructor):

```
    private static readonly int MaxDeviceNumber = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxDeviceNumber"]);
    private static readonly int MinDeviceNumber = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MinDeviceNumber"]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.cctor` is the *static* constructor. This fits with the fact that you have a type initializer exception. It looks like you are trying to parse an `int` in the static constructor of `NatMappingManager`, but the value you are passing to it is `null`.

(If you don't have an explicit static constructor, look for a static member that is being initialized on the same line that it is declared.)

Comment: Correct! I was missing some Setting values that should be there. Thanks a lot, accepting answer when it's 15 minutes. I am also changing the title to be clearer.